# Dynamic Text Sizing in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, nsattributedstring, dynamic-type-feature

I'm trying to support *Large Font Accessibility* in the app. There are places where we are using `NSAttributedString` to set the `attributedText` of a `UILabel`.

On `UILabel`, we've set `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true`. Also, in the attributes, we're using `UIFontMetrics` to allow the label to adapt to the size changes.

```
UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .caption2).scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11))
```

**Issue:**

When I run the app, the `UILabel` displays the `attributedText` as per the device's current Size Category. But, when I change the size category from device's accessibility settings, the `UILabel` is not updated accordingly.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using accessibility inspector to update the size? because when you change accessibility in Settings, the view is re-rendered, and you should see "current" settings again.

Comment: I'm using an actual device to change the accessibility settings. Is there a way to reflect the updated size in NSAttributedString as per the accessibility setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that's the proper way you used because it's definitely the method I abide by (and it works).

I created a blank project in `Interface Builder` *(Xcode 13.4.1)* as follows:

[image]

I code the `UILabel` text as `NSAttributedString` to follow your pattern plus some other stuff for the `Dynamic Type` feature:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        let myText = NSAttributedString(string: "hello C.A.P.T.I.O.N. 2")
        myLabel.attributedText = myText
    
        myLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        myLabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .caption2).scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11.0))
    }
}
```

Finally, I get this result on an `iPhoneProMax` (15.6.1):

[image]

I don't know what's inside your code but, following this rationale, you're now able to **use the Dynamic Text Sizing in NSAttributedString**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that settings .font in NSAttributedString results in label not resizing accordingly with accessibility settings. By removing it and adding label.font property it worked fine.

Comment: setting `label.font` will overwrite the font attribute and remove any occurrences of  bold or italics as well as different font sizes in your text. So it is only a solution of your attributed string doesn't use the font attribute.